# I am trying to refresh the div without refreshing the entire page using $( "#div" ).load(window.location.href + " #div" ); it is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to refresh this div but I keep getting this error XMLHttpRequest cannot load. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

I have researched that firefox had allowed cross http requests but when I reload the page the div disappears.

I am wondering if there is something wrong with my codes.

The data that I am retrieving is from firebase.

```
function updateDiv(){ 
  $("#data-container").load(window.location.href + " #data-container");
}
```

```html
<div data-role="page" id="pageone">
  <div data-role="header">
    <button onclick="goBack()">Back</button>
    <h1>Transaction History</h1>
  </div>
  <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for Name..">
  <button onclick="updateDiv()"></button>
  <div id="data-container"></div>
```

Comment: It would make more sense to create an endpoint that returns just the HTML you need. That said, are you running the HTML on your local filesystem? Ie. does the URL start `file://...`?

Comment: yes i am running it on localhost

Answer (score -1):

You're calling a load on the actual page (window.location.href) for the content of #data-container, and you want to put the content into #data-container. On your code, the content of #data-container is empty, so you replace "empty" by empty". I don't know what you really want to do ?

For your Cross Origin problem you should try to call a relative path instead of window.location.href. For example if you're on http://localhost/test.php you should write .load('test.php #data-container').

Can you explain a bit what your are trying to do ? What do you call "refresh the div" ? You want to restore it's content with original content, because it can be modified after page load (with JS for example) ? If yes, you should store the initial content of the div in JS cache :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#data-container').data('cache',jQuery('#data-container').html)) ;
}) ;
```

Then when you want to restore it's original content, you don't have to make an ajax call, you just have to get the stored content :

```
function updateDiv(){ 
  $("#data-container").html(jQuery('#data-container').data('cache'))
```

;
    }

But, tbh, i think this not what you're trying to do, right ? You're trying to search for datas containing jQuery('input#myInput').val() ?

Comment: actually i am retrieving data from firebase so that the data in the div will be updated and replaced with the old set of data  once the user clicks on the button

Comment: Can you add a set of example ? what you have init, what you have before pressing button, what you want after button click.

Comment: i have added the set of example below

Comment: Where ? can't see

Answer (score -1):

This is what I have on page load it will retrieve all the transaction from firebase and update accordingly to the list.

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {

                // [START_EXCLUDE silent]

                // [END_EXCLUDE]
                if (user) {
                    uid = user.displayName;
                    console.log(uid);
                    var rootRef = firebase.database().ref();
                    var ref = rootRef.child(uid + "/Transaction History");
                    var query = ref.orderByKey().limitToLast(100);
                    query.on("child_added", function(messageSnapshot) {
                        // This will only be called for the last 100 messages
                        var keys = Object.keys(messageSnapshot);
                        var messageData = messageSnapshot.val();
                        var key = messageSnapshot.getKey();
                        console.log("key is " + messageSnapshot.getKey());
                        console.log("messagesnapshot is " + messageSnapshot);

                        var obj = {
                            key: key,
                            firstName: messageData.firstName,
                            lastName: messageData.lastName,
                            icNo: messageData.icNo,
                            passportNo: messageData.passportNo
                        };
                        arr.push(obj);
                        ref.child(key + "/User Information").once('value').then(function(snapshot) {

                            var name = snapshot.val().firstName;
                            console.log(name);

                            s = "<li><a href='#'>" + no + '. '+ name + ' ' + key +"</a></li>";
    no++
                            sources.push(s)
                                //  for ( property in messageSnapshot) {
                                //   console.log( property ); // Outputs: foo, fiz or fiz, foo
                                //}

                            //$("#mylist").html(s);
                            //$("#mylist").listview("refresh");

                            console.log("arr.length is " + arr.length);
                            console.log(sources[9]);

                        }).then(function(pagination) {
                            Pagination();
                        })
```

After pressing the button it will refresh the div with the newly updated transactions that are retrieved from firebase in the data container

```
function updateDiv(){ 
   $( "#data-container" ).load(window.location.href + " #data-container" );
}

    </script>
</head>

<body>

    <div data-role="page" id="pageone">
        <div data-role="header">
            <button onclick="goBack()">Back</button>

            <h1>Transaction History</h1>
        </div>
        <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for Name..">
        <button onclick="updateDiv()"></button>


        <div id="data-container"></div>
        <div id="mylist"></div>
```